# What should I do to make this 960 Grid layout?

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I'm relatively new to discovering the 960 Grid system, and its a bit different than what I'm used to working on. My main question today, is that I'm trying to make a layout that will look like this image.
How would I write the code to make this simple layout for example in 960 Grid format???

[image]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

First, you can find some 960 grid template or framework.

For example,

- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/): Twitter Bootstrap provides almost all basic elements for building a website.
- [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) : If you only want a 960 grid layout with you own style, this is a good solution.

There are more option on internet. It is not difficult to google it.

And then take a look on the example code they provide. Try it and you can know how to use 960 grid: [Skelton Grid](http://www.getskeleton.com/#grid)